# Why is this Media Query not working?

Tags: css, media-queries

I feel like I'm about to feel very silly in a second, but I can't for the life of me figure out what's wrong with my media query. I'm using Adobe's Brackets as my code editor, and originally thought there was a glitch in the program. But then I tested the code in jsFiddle and it's not working there either, so I must be fudging something up with the code.

Can anyone see what's wrong?

Here is my [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vgrtety9/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="helpful">

<span class="thumb">Did you find this helpful?</span>
<span class="readers">82 Readers found this helpful</span>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.helpful .readers {
    color: #35cb1a;
    font-size: .9em;
}

.helpful .thumb {
    float: right;
    color: #7b7b7b;
    font-size: .9em;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1020px) {

    .helpful .readers,
    .helpful .thumb {
        display: block;
        margin: auto;
     }
 }
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong cause you didn't say what was wrong. "Not working" is not a technical description.

Comment: What do you want the media query to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`display: block; margin: auto` on elements with no specified width has no effect, since [blocks with auto width stretch to the full width of their container leaving no room for margins](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#blockwidth).

Furthermore, auto margins have no effect on a floated element, and [a floated element is `display: block` by definition](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#dis-pos-flo).

So your media query is working, but the styles in it don't have any apparent effect on the given layout.

- If you want the floated element to stop floating at 1020px and narrower, you need to override the `float` declaration.
- If you want the text to be centered, use `text-align: center` instead of `margin: auto`.
- If you want the two elements to stack vertically, keep the `display: block` declaration.

[Putting it all together](https://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/vgrtety9/4):

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1020px) {
    .helpful .readers,
    .helpful .thumb {
        display: block;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .helpful .thumb {
        float: none;
    }
}
```

Comment: There it is! I knew I was missing something. For some reason I thought simply declaring `block` and an auto margin would override the float. Not sure why I thought that. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

you code is perfectly fine as you want to centre align those div after some 1020px width and for that you have use this css

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1020px) {

    .helpful .readers,
    .helpful .thumb {
        display: block;
        margin: auto;
     }
 }
```

But you always need to mention `width` if you are using `margin:auto`.

I am assuming width of 200px so css should be like this

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1020px) {

    .helpful .readers,
    .helpful .thumb {
        display: block;
        margin: auto;
        widht:200px;
     }
 }
```

Working fine in this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/vgrtety9/3/

Comment: I made width as a CSS element more prominent